# AWS | Using Cognito for a Django server via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a Django server running on an EC2 machine, which also serves the UI built by Vue.js. For authentication and user management-related stuff, I have introduced Cognito service. I am using Cognito hosted UI as well for login, sign up, etc. I am also using API Gateway to make sure the Django REST APIs cannot be accessed without authentication.

There are two Routes in my API Gateway:

1. /api/{x} this is for REST calls and that is getting authorized by Cognito using Bearer token.
2. A route with a wildcard for the rest of the UI-related URLs (those are not authorized).

Both the Routes are integrated with the Django server running on the EC2 machine.

Things are working perfectly when I invoke API Gateway URL. The Cognito integration is working like a gem. But the problem is: when I'm trying to access the Django server using the public IP of the EC2 machine. I can call the RESTs without authentication using the public IP.

This is where I am getting stuck. How to overcome this kind of scenario? How can I restrict access by public IP? Or, is there a better approach that I should follow?

I am very much new to AWS. Any suggestion from your end is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate public access to your Django EC2 instance by restricting the web traffic in the EC2 security group attached to the EC2 instance. Then create a network load balancer in the same VPC as your instance and allow web traffic to your django instance from the subnets associated with the VPC via your security group.

Finally, create a VPC link for the API gateway which uses the newly created NLB as an endpoint. This would allow the API gateway to route requests inbound to the EC2 instance via the linked network load balancer (enforcing your Cognito authentication), while preventing internet traffic at large from reaching the the EC2 instance without being forwarded via API gateway.